# git merge is unobtrusively changing the history

Tags: git

I've two branches, let's say *branch-A* and *branch-B*.

*branch-A* got the history changed, while *branch-B* kept the old history. A new feature has been developed on *branch-B* and I'd like to bring it on *branch-A*, without bringing also the history of *branch-B*.

For simplicity sake, let's suppose that the feature is entirely contained in the file *feature.txt*.

Now I understand that this is not as easy as it looks, since git doesn't know where the commits of the new feature are, and I should tell it where the new feature begins and where it ends, so something like this:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-first-commit-feature>..<hash-last-commit-feature>
```

What I don't understand is why if I execute:

```
git checkout branch-A
git merge branch-B --no-commit --no-ff
```

I only see among the outgoing files only *feature.txt*, so it looks like I can correctly commit and push to origin.

However, after I execute `git add feature.txt`, `git commit` and then `git log origin/branch-A..branch-A` I can see that the differences isn't only *feature.txt*, but I just brought all the history of *branch-B* on *branch-A*.

What amazes me the most is that if I execute `git push` it will change the remote history, and git won't complain a bit about this. I expected that the use of `--force` was the only way to change the history.

Why am I experiencing this behavior? Is there a way to prevent history changes to be unintentionally pushed?

In the end, looks like that git knows that the only difference between the two branches is *feature.txt*, since it shows me only this difference when I merge with `--no-commit`. Is there a way to tell git that I don't want the whole history to be merged?

Comment: are you looking for `git rebase --onto branch-A branch-B feature` ? This will basically cherry-pick all commits in `branch-B..feature` on top of `branch-A` (note that in git, a range such as  `branch-B..feature` includes the last commit, but *excludes* the first one, you need to mention the *parent* of `hash-first-commit` if it happens to not be `branch-B`)

Comment: @LeGEC what is `feature` in your command?

Comment: `feature` would be the name of your feature branch, or it can be a plain commit hash.

Comment: ok thank you, this can make me save time. But this doesn't explain why git only shows me the feature when I type `git merge --no-commit` and then `git status`

Comment: by the way both `git cherry-pick` and `git rebase` fail because `branch-B` has some other merges in the history, thus `git cherry-pick --continue` will eventually refuse to work

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you have two branches with a substantial part of their history that differs (which you hinted at with "branch-A git the history changed"), but there is no description of *what* got changed.

If the only thing that got changed in the history was some metadata in the commits (for example: the name+email of the authors of the commits), then `branch-A` and `branch-B` will have the exact same content at their tips.

This goes towards the "why do I only see `feature` in the diff when I merge ?" :

compare your branches before feature:

```
git diff branch-A <branch-B before feature>
```

if there is no diff there, then it is only logical that the only extra modifications in content will come from `feature`.

---

As far as histories go, the very *purpose* of `git merge` is to create a commit which combines both histories: the resulting commit will have both `branch-A` and `branch-B` as parents, and will thus list both histories when you inspect the history of these parents.

Since this commit it is a legitimate descendant of `branch-A`, pushing doesn't require `--force` -- you will note that none of the existing commits got rewritten, there is no "history change" as you name it.

It so happens that the commit is *also* a descendant of `branch-B`, and you simply seem to want to avoid that.

---

The go to commands for porting commits from one branch to another without pulling in the history are `git cherry-pick` and `git rebase`.

If porting the history that landed on branch-B also happens to drag in commits which merge some earlier states of the repo, you will have to review in a more thorough way what needs to be ported.